# What happened to the package explorer in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, auto-update

I have recently been setting up SVN in Eclipse using the Subversive plugin (I am still a bit lost, but that's another issue).

I have been using this guide (http://soledadpenades.com/2008/12/10/add-svn-support-to-your-eclipse-installation/) and finally got it working!
The only problem now is, I can't seem to find the Package Explorer, which is the only explorer I could ever seem to get working how I wanted it to (grouping projects into working sets).

Normally, you get it from going to *Window* → *Show View* → *Other*, and then select it from the list. The only thing is, it's not IN the list of views... leaving me rather confused.

Just to be clear, I was using the package explorer before with no problems. I am running the latest version of everything as I did the auto update.

Any suggestions as to what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three answerers were helpful, however the only cure was to reinstall Eclipse and install the plugins again. Weird problem, and the exact cause not found. I may have deleted some files somehow, but a reinstall solved it.

Answer (score 39):

I'm guessing you've made it a [fast view or minimised](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-21.htm) it to it. You could try holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to see a list of all views, then up/down arrow to the View. If Package Explorer is in the list it has been minimised or something.

If you select it and still can't see it, try *Window* → *Reset Perspective...* to restore all views to their defaults.

Comment: Tried first suggestion, nice shortcut, but it isn't there.
Tried the second suggestion, I think I have somehow lost the original java perspective... any idea how to get it back?

Comment: "Reset Perspective" is what gets it back.

Comment: When I click Window > Open Perspective, I see only debug as the defaults where I used to see Java AND Debug... odd

Comment: hmm only thing I can think of is that you've clobbered one of the core jdt plugins. When you view installed plugins how many org.eclipse.jdt plugins do you see?

Comment: I have 31 in my Galileo installation, maybe you deleted some by mistake?

Comment: *sigh* I think I will HAVE to reinstall... Thanks anyway though.

Comment: even by reset perspective it does not come back. but it shows in Java Browsing perspective. wierd.

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> worked for me when I was in debug mode.

Answer (score 10):

Weirdly enough, although reset perspective didn't work, menu *Window* → *New window* worked! It opened a new window with the perspectives reset.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. It magically came back!

Answer (score 6):

For me I needed to do two things:

- Reinstall the "Eclipse Java development tools" via *Help* → *Install Software* → *Programming Languages*
- Delete and recreate the .metadata Eclipse Workspace settings.

Honestly, deleting the .metadata directory is probably sufficient - try that first.

Answer (score 4):

At the top right corner, there is a button called *Open Perspective*. Click on it, and then *Java Default*. Everything will come back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are in the Java perspective?

As views are related to perspectives this could be the problem. The current perspective can be found in the upper right corner.

Comment: Any view can be shown in any perspective, the perspective just defines the default views. So the package explorer should still be in the list

Comment: I am indeed in the java perspective, although it isnt using the same icon as my laptop version of eclipse. How do I make sure I'm using the default original? The text in the perspective is "<Java>"

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing the JDT plugin containing the Package Explorer.

Comment: How can I tell? and if so, how can I reinstall it? I only just managed to get it how I wanted before lol

Comment: You can browse through the installed packages under Help -> Install New Software ... and click the link "What is already installed?" near the bottom. Check for Eclipse Java Development Tools.

Comment: If it is missing, install from the Galileo repository.

Comment: ok. on the list of installed, I can see "Java Development Toolkit JUnit runtime support" and the same again but with JUnit4.
I selected Galileo in the install new software dropdown, and filtered for JDT. I get one result which was in the Java EE Development section, "Eclipse Faceted Project Framework JDT Enablement", and judging by the description of what it is, it doesnt inclue the package explorer.
Thanks for your help on this, any further suggestions or more direct pointers?

Comment: If however its not a plugin, I can see in the list of installed software "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers > EPP Java Package > Eclipse Java Development Tools". Is that the one?

Comment: Yes. Seems this is not the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were actually still in the Debug perspective, since that was what did it for me. As someone mentioned above, I had to go to the top right and hit "Java perspective" to get back to my normal views.

Answer (score 0):

On the right top you can select Java or JRE or whatever. That button might got changed. So click the neighbor buttons such as Java or something.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> perspective -> Open Perspective -> Java. Now all the packages in Java will be displayed in the package explorer.