# How to show the package explorer in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats happened to the package explorer in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497912/whats-happened-to-the-package-explorer-in-eclipse)

I am really new to programming as well as android development. I am following a tutorial. On one of the screens on the left there should be the Package explorer, but i can't find it. Can someone please tell how I can get this on eclipse?

Answer (score 20):

Either you're not in the correct perspective or you've closed the Package explorer panel.

Click on Window > Open Perspective > Java.

If you don't see 'Java' as an option then you're already in that perspective. In which case do:

Window > Reset Perspective.

Answer (score 11):

> Window -> Show View -> Package Explorer

adds it to the workspace.